In libibverbs, when does completion entry get pushed to CQ?

After a wr has been posted through ibv_post_send to a RC, does completion entry get pushed to sender's cq when data has been written to destination buffer and the sender receive an acknowledgement?

After a wr has been posted through ibv_post_send to a UD, does completion happen as soon as data has been copied out of the local buffer?

For the above three cases, do behave differently if it is IBV_WR_RDMA_WRITE vs IBV_WR_SEND?


